# Add list of figures, tables, etc on different position in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, positioning

I have a LaTeX document with some chapter and a list of figures and tables.
Something like this:

```
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
```

So the result in the table of contents would be:

List of tables ................... i
List of figures ................. ii
Chapter 1 .................... 1
Chapter 2 .................... 2
Chapter 3 .................... 3

**But i want to have in the document the lists at the beginning and in the table of contents i want them at the end, like this:**

Chapter 1 ...................... 1
Chapter 2 ...................... 2
Chapter 3 ...................... 3
**List of tables ................ i**
**List of figures .............. ii**

I tried this:

```
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\chapter{section 1}
\chapter{section 2}
\chapter{section 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
```

But then the page number is wrong:

Chapter 1 .................... 1
Chapter 2 .................... 2
Chapter 3 .................... 3
List of tables ............... **4**
List of figures ............. **5**

**Does anyone know a solution, how to change the position of the lists in the toc with the correct page number?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) allows you to extract page references in an expandable way. The following method uses the `\label`-`\ref` system to set a `\label` on the first page of the LoF/LoT and then add the entries to the ToC where they are needed, expanding the page number using `\getpagerefnumber`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\label{listoffigures}
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\label{listoftables}
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapter{Third chapter}

% Insert delayed LoF/LoT
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\listfigurename}{\getpagerefnumber{listoffigures}}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\listtablename}{\getpagerefnumber{listoftables}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice answers! As you mentioned, i use hyperref. So if i add two {} at the end, it compiles: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\listfigurename}{\getpagerefnumber{listoffigures}}{}{}}`. But now there is no hyperlink on it. I found solutions for the hyperlink to the actual chapter: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\listfigurename}{\getpagerefnumber{listoffigures}}{chapter*.\thechapter}{}}`. But i don't know how to link to the LoF? I tried things like `\ref{listoffigures}`, `\pageref{listoffigures}`, but it not works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Below is a very special use-case for your scenario. I'm sure it'll need more work if you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or other ToC-related packages.

The idea is to update the macro that sets every ToC-related entry to condition specifically on whether it's setting the LoF or the LoT. Here's what your typical `.toc` would look like:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Figures}{ii}
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Tables}{iv}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}First chapter}{1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Second chapter}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Third chapter}{5}
```

We conditionally check using a `str`ing `c`o`mp`arison between the second argument of `\contentsline` whether it matches either `\listfigurename` or `\listtablename`. If that's the case, we store all the information for use later (in macros `\delayedLoF` and `\delayedLoT`). These macros are then inserted into the ToC using `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect<macro>}` to set the entry wherever you call it within the document.

The insertions are `\protect`ed so as to not expand, but the eventual `.toc` will resemble

```
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Figures}{ii}
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Tables}{iv}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}First chapter}{1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Second chapter}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Third chapter}{5}
\delayedLoF 
\delayedLoT
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

% Update \contentsline to condition on LoF/LoT
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{\listfigurename}=0
    \def\delayedLoF{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{\listtablename}=0
    \def\delayedLoT{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
  \else
    \oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}
  \fi\fi
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapter{Third chapter}

% Insert delayed LoF/LoT
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\delayedLoF}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\delayedLoT}

\end{document}
```

If your LoF and LoT entries will necessarily be at the end of the ToC, one could just patch `\tableofcontents` to insert them automatically.