# List of Figures at the end of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the list of figures and the list of tables, and I want them to appear at the end of the Contents List. See in the following image:
[image]

that the list of Figures and Tables are at the beginning of the contents, but i want them at the end. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Moving `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` to the end of the document should help ;-) The entry is made at that position where the you use the commands. (Assuming you're using `tocbibind` or applying `\addcontentsline` directly)

Comment: please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321132/add-list-of-figures-tables-etc-on-different-position-in-table-of-contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the below to the end of the document saved the day.

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\listfigurename}{\getpagerefnumber{listoffigures}}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\listtablename}{\getpagerefnumber{listoftables}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: however, the funny thing is that sometimes it works, and sometimes it gives an error. Why is that?

Comment: If you encounter errors by this it's not yet an answer, in my point of view -- the above fragment is not really useful for others that have the same problem since all of the remaining setup is not visible