# remove numbering from list of figures and list of tables but have them in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am working on a document. In my document I want to include page numbers of list of figures and list of table in my table of contents but I do not want to number the list of figures and list of tables. The first chapter is introduction so I want to have introduction becomes number 1. I use the following code in my document:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
 \renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
 \tocsection
 \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
 \endgroup}
 \begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \frontmatter
 \tableofcontents
 \newpage
 \listoffigures
 \newpage
 \listoftables
  \mainmatter
 \newcommand{\sectionbreak} {\clearpage}
 \section{Introduction}
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \clearpage
 \bibliographystyle{apacite}
 \bibliography{bibfile}
 \end{document}
```

The issue that I have is that when I write this code, it numbers list of figures and list of tables but I only need to include them in my TOC. Currently it looks like below image:

[image]

And list of figures is numbered:

[image]

While I do not like that 1 behind list of figures.

I tried other codes in the forum. For example I tried to replace

```
\tableofcontents
 \newpage
 \listoffigures
 \newpage
 \listoftables
```

by

```
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
\chapter{Introduction}
```

from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321132/add-list-of-figures-tables-etc-on-different-position-in-table-of-contents) which I customized it for my own document, but it did not work, and after running I observed that in one line I have introduction, list of figures and list of tables. Even they had overlaps to each other. It looks like below figure after replacing:

[image]

I really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Would you mind to provide a full compilable example instead of just two fragments?

Comment: @marmot I edited it. I hope it be more clear now.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also add your `\documentclass` command? As well as some figure environment?

Comment: Those lists are unnumbered by default.

Comment: @marmot I added \documentclass and a snap of list of figures. Does this work as a figure environment?

Comment: @Johannes_B But how come they are numbered here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `tocbibind` includes LoF and LoT unnumbered in ToC. The list of figures gets numbered if you redefine `\listoffigures` using command `\tocsection`. So you only have to remove this redefinition of `\listoffigures` to get an unnumbered LoF including a ToC entry.

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

 \begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \tableofcontents
 \newpage
 \listoffigures
 \newpage
 \listoftables

 \cleardoublepage
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \section{Introduction}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` are undefined for `article` class.